# Add Column Name to multiple sheets in an EXCEL using VBA or any other means

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with 365 sheets. I would like to add column names to the three columns present in each sheet. I want the first column = height, second column = direction and third column = velocity. Also I want it to start on row 1. How do I go about this in excel. Keep in mind I have 365 sheets in total. I'm appreciative of any guidance/help. Thanks[image: sheet showing values]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty straightforward once you know how.

Shift-click the sheets that you want to have the headers added to. Since you're working with so many sheets, the fastest way to do this would be to select the first, scroll all the way to the last and shift click that one.

On one of the selected sheets, simply right click on the first row header and select insert. Type the column names in cells A1, B1, C1 (making sure all your sheets are still selected at the bottom). The changes you're making to the visible sheet will also be happening to the selected sheets.

Let me know if this doesn't work, you could also do it with a macro but this seems the fastest method.

Comment: @CaptBallistic...Thank you very much! It is well appreciated!